# VPN tunnel via IPSec

Tags: centos, vpn, ipsec

I'm not so familiar with installing and configuring VPN connections, but I need to link up our web server (CentOS 6) to a Cisco 3945. Here is the information I have from the Cisco device:

```
VPN Device Tunnel Endpoint IP Address: 91.151.a.b
Host(s):  IP address(es) to be accessed (Public IP address required): 91.151.c.d
Phase 1 & 2 Encryption Type: 3DES/SHA1
VPN scheme: IKE
Phase 1 encryptin algorithm: 3DES
Phase 1 hash algorithm: Secure Hash Standard
Phase 1 authentication method: Pre-Shared Key
Phase 1 algorithm: Diffie-Hellman Group 2 (1024 bit)
Phase 1 lifetime: 86400 seconds
Phase 2 perfect forward secrecy (yes/no): No
Phase 2 encryption algorithm: 3DES
Phase 2 hash algorithm: Secure Hash Standard
Phase 2 lifetime: 3600 seconds
```

I'm trying to find some tutorials but most of them seem to be old and out dated. Could anyone gives me a straightforward help on what applications I can use and if it's possible some helps or hints on commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SF isn't really a substitute for google, but **one possible way** you could go is openswan.

1) Get openswan, the userspace toolchain's in the standard repository, with `sudo yum install openswan`.

2) Configure your tunnel, perhaps by putting something like this in `/etc/ipsec.conf`:

```
conn MYNAME
        # Left endpoint, subnet behind it, next hop toward right
        keyingtries=0
        left=MY-ADDRESS
        leftsubnet=MY-ADDRESS/32
        leftnexthop=MY-NEXT-HOP-ROUTE
        # Right endpoint, subnet behind it, next hop toward left
        right=CISCO-ADDRESS
        rightsubnet=CISCO-ADDRESS/32
        type=tunnel
        authby=secret
        #auth=esp
        keylife=1h
        ikelifetime=1h
        #esp=3des-md5-96
        #pfs=no
        #compress=no
        #keyexchange=ike
        auto=start
```

This configuration is taken from another CentOS 6 box, linked via IPSec to a CISCO router of some kind, so hopefully it can be fairly easily adapted for your use.  You will need to change all the values in **CAPITALS**.  `MYNAME` is a simple text string that names your tunnel; it's only used locally, for disambiguation; the other values are hopefully self-evident.

3) Put the pre-shared key in `/etc/ipsec.secrets`, as

```
MY-ADDRESS CISCO-ADDRESS: PSK "ALongAndVeryRandomString"
```

Here you need to set all values except "PSK", which is a configuration marker that should remain unchanged.  The LongString is a pre-shared random key that the CISCO will need to know as well.

You don't say if you have to configure the CISCO end as well; I'm really hoping you've got someone with network clue to do that bit for you.

Once it's done, bring the tunnel up on the CentOS box with `sudo service ipsec start`.  Find out if it's working with `sudo ipsec auto --status|grep MYNAME`; you're looking for a non-zero IPSec SA (IPSec SA non-zero is identically equivalent to "tunnel is up").

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help indeed. Fortunately I'm not supposed to configure the Cisco device, all I need is to link up our CentOS to it. One more question; I don't have the _Subnet Mask_ for the Cisco device, should I use a default value for that?

Comment: If you're referring to the mask in `rightsubnet`, it isn't a subnet mask, it's an address mask showing the **range** of destination addresses that are to be routed via this tunnel.  If you're only talking to the CISCO itself via this tunnel, that's `/32`.  If instead you're doing some kind of VPN thing, and routing to an RFC1918 destination network via this CISCO, say, you might use `rightsubnet=172.18.4.0/24`, if that were the remote network.

Comment: with openswan clients behind same nat cannot connect to the server can you suggest a way around @MadHatter