# Configuring IPSec

Tags: centos6, ipsec, openswan

If you look at my [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/474473/vpn-tunnel-via-ipsec), you'll see that I have two IP Addresses (for the remote device), to configuring our VPN Tunnel:

```
VPN Device Tunnel Endpoint IP Address: 91.151.a.b
Host(s):  IP address(es) to be accessed (Public IP address required): 91.151.c.d
```

During the IPSec configuration, I need to provide our machine's IP address (left) and the remote device (right), but I still have no idea which of above IP addresses, for the remote device, is the right one for configuring IPSec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if `right=91.151.a.b`, and `rightsubnet=91.151.c.d/32`, but as you say, it's unclear.  Try both - one of them definitely won't work!

Whichever host is `right`, that will also need to be one of the addresses listed, along with your own, in the `PSK` line of the `...secrets` file.